# How can I make this background image responsive? wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

Ok so I have a custom wordpress theme and have tried multiple different ways to get this to work.

The issue I'm having is that on mobile screens and small screens it crops the image instead of rescaling it to fit the screen.

I'm trying to edit the splash img here's the code.

```
    .stockimage {
/*background-image:url('../img/guitarpic.jpg');*/
background-image:url('../img/splash-2.png');
background-size:100% 100%;
background-size:cover;
background-position:center center;

}
```

I've also tried bootstrap etc but to no avail I haven't got it to work as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by removing background-size:cover; and replacing with background-size: 100% 100%